# How can I programmatically assign or unassign a startup program in C# MSIX?

Tags: c#, startup

I succeed in designating a program to be executed when Windows starts with MSIX package in C#.
Now I also know that can access the Task Manager and assign or unassign a program as a startup program.

But the question is, can this be done internally 'C# programming'?

I would like to directly mount it on the UI of the product to support assign/unassign of startup programs more conveniently for users who are not familiar with using computers.
(Note: MSIX packages are not registry registered.)

I followed the process provided in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#start-your-application-in-different-ways) to solve this problem.

```
<desktop:StartupTask
    TaskId="StartupTaskID"
    Enabled="false"
    DisplayName="AppName" />
```

Additionally, the desktop:StartupTask:Enabled option only seems to have an effect on initial app deployment. (So, if the app is already installed, modifying that variable has no effect.)

Does anyone know how to solve a problem like this?
thanks for reading.